# where in msdn downloads is windows 7 service pack 1

Tags: windows-7

I may need new glasses. Where in MSDN downloads can I get Windows 7 Service Pack 1? Precise file description would also help to ensure i download the right thing.

Additional : yes I have login to msdn to get downloads

Comment: Not really a programming question.

Comment: @Briedis: sorry, maybe should have asked this on servervault. I have flagged for moderator action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Windows 7 and Window Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (x86 and x64) - DVD (Multilanguage)` under `Windows 7`.

Comment: Thank you. i think the size of 2Gb made me think it was the whole OS

Comment: @Valamas: No; the whole OS is bigger than that.  It's very large because it includes 35 languages.